# async.EachSeries not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, es6-promise, async.js

I have created a promise to return the result when async.eachSeries will finish its task, when the array has four elements it only display one element in final response. I want to display all elements in array as a final output. Below is the code and is this approach is correct? What I have seen also when I put console.log under the membersProcessed++ it first displays all console.log and then just send one output. How to fix this issue to send all array back to the promise after the completion of async.eachSeries.

```
var members = [];

    let createMembers = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var membersProcessed = 0;
        async.eachSeries(req.body.payLoad, (member, callback) => {
            membersProcessed++;
            User.find({mobileNumber: member.mobileNumber}, (err, data) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                }  else {
                    if (data.length == 0) {
                        member.isMember = true;
                    } else {
                        member.isMember = false;
                    }
                    members.push(member);
                    if(membersProcessed < req.body.payLoad.length) {
                        resolve(members);
                    } else {
                        callback();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

    createMembers.then((data) => {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: data
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err
        });
    });
```

current output

```
{
    "message": [
        {
            "mobileNumber": "1234567891",
            "firstName": "a",
            "lastName": "aa",
            "isMember": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Output should be

```
{
    "message": [
        {
            "mobileNumber": "1234567891",
            "firstName": "a",
            "lastName": "aa",
            "isMember": true
        },
{
            "mobileNumber": "1234567892",
            "firstName": "b",
            "lastName": "bb",
            "isMember": true
        },
{
            "mobileNumber": "1234567893",
            "firstName": "c",
            "lastName": "cc",
            "isMember": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're doing Users.find({mobileNumber: contact.mobileNumber}) which means you are querying the db with specific value of mobileNumber ,if you want all the results irrespective of the filter then do directly

```
await Users.find({},(err,res)=>{
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(res))
    });
```

or if you want to fetch the records on some key basis then

```
 Users.find({mobileNumber:contact.mobileNumber},(err,result)=>{
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(result))
    });
```

the result will have the set of all the objects catered from the request made ,you can directly assign this to another object like

```
var obj=await Users.find({mobileNumber:contact.mobileNumber},(err,result)=>{
          return res.send(JSON.stringify(result))
        });
```

Comment: But the problem is with async, I cannot process all of the array. It process only one index. e,g in my payload I have four objects, it is only processing one object but not the others

Comment: @JN_newbie i believe you should use await keyword inside your async functions,as they chain the output until the async function has finished executing,see the edit above

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have resolve the issue. It was due to the not initialization of a Model. I don't if really it was due to this. But I will surely use solution as well

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you used the condition wrongly, you can change your condition like this.it's working fine. because of you use promise, anyway your condition satisfy the first iteration itself **if(membersProcessed < req.body.payLoad.length)** so you can change your condition like **if(membersProcessed == req.body.payLoad.length)**

```
 if(membersProcessed == req.body.payLoad.length) {
    resolve(members);
 } else {
    callback();
 }
```